# Margin for dynamic TextView from style not applied

Tags: c#, android-layout, xamarin.android

I have a LinearLayout container which I am populating with TextViews. I've created a style for these TextViews in styles.xml. Problem is that margin is not applied when I create textviews dynamically in code-behind and apply the style. All the other values from style actually work.

I am working in VS 2019, project is Xamarin Android native app (not forms).
When I populate LinearyLayout manually with TextViews and apply the style it works correctly, margin is applied. It only does not work when TextView is created in code behind. Also it is possible to set margin programmatically using LayoutParams and SetMargin function.
Although I'd rather not have part of the style defined in xml and one small bit in code behind.

This is the TextView style:

```
<style name="TextView.Tag" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/ColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:paddingHorizontal">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingVertical">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/ColorTextOnSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">8dp</item>
 </style>
```

This is LinearLayout container:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/TeaTagsLayoutContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingVertical="4dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/TeaCategoryLayout"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TeaCategoryImage">
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code which adds creates text view and puts it into the container:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context, null, 0, Resource.Style.TextView_Tag)
{
    Text = "tag text";
};

tagsLayoutContainer.AddView(tv);
```

I expect whole style defined in style.xml to work with dynamically created TextViews.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, `android:layout_*` attributes are `LayoutParams`. They are arguments to the parent and affect how the parent will perform layout on that view. Since it doesn't know which parent the `TextView` is going to end up in on creating it, the layout attributes are dropped.

Since `LayoutParams` are specific to the parent view type, one solution would be to supply an instance of the correct parent type when you inflate layouts using a `LayoutInflater` or else `layout_` attributes on the top-level view in the layout will be dropped. (The inflater would have no idea what type of `LayoutParams` to generate.)

Comment: Hi Raimo, thanks for quick response. I was able to solve the issue thanks to the information you provided.